# Issue in Running Unit test using Karma for Angular Project in GitLab CI

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, karma-runner

I am getting below error :

- 313 $ npm run test
- 314 > angular-base-line@0.0.0 test /builds/8800/IT/EAPC/base-line-project/angular
- 315 > ng test
- 316 30 01 2020 10:45:00.853:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
- 317 30 01 2020 10:45:00.894:INFO [karma-server]: Karma v4.4.1 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
- 318 30 01 2020 10:45:00.895:INFO [launcher]: Launching browsers ChromeHeadlessCustom with concurrency unlimited
- 319 30 01 2020 10:45:00.903:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser ChromeHeadless
- ........
- ........
- 337 30 01 2020 10:45:06.908:WARN [launcher]: ChromeHeadless have not captured in 6000 ms, killing.
- 338 30 01 2020 10:45:08.909:WARN [launcher]: ChromeHeadless was not killed in 2000 ms, sending SIGKILL.
- 339 30 01 2020 10:45:10.912:WARN [launcher]: ChromeHeadless was not killed by SIGKILL in 2000 ms, continuing.

My karma conf file

```js
module.exports = function (config) {

  const process = require('process');
  process.env.CHROME_BIN = require('puppeteer').executablePath();

  config.set({
    basePath: '',

    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('phantomjs-prebuilt'),
      //require('karma-phantomjs-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client:{
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, 'coverage'), reports: [ 'html', 'lcovonly' ],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },

    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browserSocketTimeout: 6000,
    browserNoActivityTimeout: 6000,
    captureTimeout: 6000,
    browserDisconnectTimeout : 6000,
    browserDisconnectTolerance : 1,
     customLaunchers: {
      ChromeHeadlessCustom: {
            base: 'ChromeHeadless',
            flags: [
              '--headless',
              '--disable-gpu',
            '--no-sandbox',
            '--no-proxy-server',
            '--disable-web-security'
            ]
          }
    }, 
      browsers: ['ChromeHeadlessCustom'],
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

- My Yaml file

```
development-tests:
  image: node:8-alpine
  stage: tests
  tags: 
      - ci-cd
  environment: Development
  only:
  - master
  #dependencies:
  # - development-build

  script:

     - apk update && apk upgrade && \
     - echo @edge http://nl.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community >> /etc/apk/repositories && \
     - echo @edge http://nl.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main >> /etc/apk/repositories && \
     #- apk add --no-cache bash chromium@edge nss@edge
     - apk add --no-cache g++ chromium 
     - export CHROME_BIN="/usr/bin/chromium-browser"
     - export PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD="true"
     - export SASS_BINARY_NAME="linux-x64-67"
     - npm install --save-dev puppeteer karma-chrome-launcher
     - npm i puppeteer
     - npm install
     - npm run test
```

- Any solutions for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you do npm test locally does it works?
I can reproduce the case with pupeeter where it works locally but not on docker Gitlab CI

- gitlabci.yml

```yaml
image: node:latest
before_script :
  #this is line 96 in the pipeline log
  - pwd
  - ls /usr
  #- export CHROME_BIN=/usr/local/bin/my-chrome-build


stages:
  - build
  - test

cache:
  paths:
    - node_modules/

install_dependencies:
  stage: build
  script:
    - npm install
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - node_modules/

testing_testing:
  stage: test
  script: npm test --log-level=DEBUG
```

- Karma conf

```js
process.env.CHROME_BIN = require('puppeteer').executablePath()


module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    browsers : ['Chrome']
  });
};
```